# Pass foreach id outside loop to update a form

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I want to update the status of permission time by time and the permissions will be given depending on the role given.

Each role has its own Id and it is being displayed but I also have to update permission with respect to the Role id but with foreach loop is given out to the form my UI is just scattered. So any way how to give id to the form to update the elements in form

```
               <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                    <a href="#" id="createType" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Positions</a>
                    @foreach($data as $key=>$item)
                    <div class="roles-menu">
                        <ul class="nav" id="item_id">
                            <li><a href="">{{ $item->name }}</a></li>
                            <input id="input" value="{{ $item->id }}">

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <form method="post" action="{{ url('/system-configurations/roles-permission/permission') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    {{--<input name="role_id" value="">--}}
                    <div class="col-sm-9 module-access">
                            <h6 class="panel-title mb-20 display-ib">Module Access</h6>
                            <div class="pull-right  mb-10">
                               {{--<select class="form-control">--}}
                                   {{--<option>Select Module</option>--}}
                               {{--</select>--}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel">
                                <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        User Management
                                        <div class="pull-right">
                                            <label class="switch">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="user_management">
                                          <span class="slider-switcher round"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        HR Management
                                        <div class="pull-right">
                                            <label class="switch">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="hr_management">
                                          <span class="slider-switcher round"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        Finance
                                        <div class="pull-right">
                                            <label class="switch">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="finance">
                                          <span class="slider-switcher round"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>                              <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-hover" id="tableBody">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Module Permission</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Read</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Write</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Create</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Import</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Export</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>User Management</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="user_management_read" checked="">
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="user_management_write" checked="">
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="user_management_create" checked="">
                                            </td>
</tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>HR Management</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="hr_management_read" checked="">
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="hr_management_write" checked="">
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="hr_management_create" checked="">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Finance</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="finance_read" checked="">
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="finance_write" checked="">
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="finance_create" checked="">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
</tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                 </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, there is no nice way to have the id outside of the loop and your template looks like I would expect.

Comment: That is the problem looks like it can be done only by javascript.